# Improve / optimize Excel macro to search for text phrases within a folder of text reports

Tags: vba, excel

Using Microsoft Excel 2010, this macro searches for a list of phrases within a folder of text reports. For each phrase, it searches all of the reports and lists each report that contains the phrase.

I found some better macros to do each part of the macro - such as enumerating a directory, or finding a phrase within a text file - although I had a really hard time putting them together successfully. Despite it not being perfect, it may be helpful for others with the same problem, and I hope for some feedback on how to improve and optimize the macro.

Basic overview:

1. Column A: list of full path to text reports (for instance, "C:\path\to\report.txt")
2. Column B: name of report (such as "report.txt")
3. Column C: list of phrases to search for
4. Columns D+: output showing each report that contains the phrase (column C)

Areas for improvement:

1. Make the macro run faster! (This took over an hour for 360 reports and 1100 phrases)
2. Select the reports and report folder from a pop-up or other function (currently entered into the spreadsheet using another macro)
3. Filter reports by file name (for instance, only check reports with a word or phrase in the file name)
4. Filter reports by file extension (for instance, only check .txt files and not .xlsx files)
5. Detect the number of reports and phrases (currently this is hard coded)
6. Other suggestions / areas for improvement

Code:

```
Sub findStringMacro()

Dim fn As String
Dim lineString As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim searchTerm As String
Dim findCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 2 To 1109
searchTerm = Range("C" & i).Value
findCount = 0
    For j = 2 To 367
    fn = Range("A" & j).Value
    fileName = Range("B" & j).Value
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn)
        Do While Not .AtEndOfStream
            lineString = .ReadLine
            If InStr(1, lineString, searchTerm, vbTextCompare) Then
                findCount = findCount + 1
                Cells(i, 3 + findCount) = fileName
                GoTo EarlyExit
            End If
        Loop
EarlyExit:
        .Close        
    End With
    Next j    
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Takes time to open 407003 files (1109 * 367).

Comment: Using the native `Workbooks.Open Filename:= fn, ReadOnly:= True` instead of using the `CreateObject()` function may shave some time off the project.

Comment: `InStr()` is a looping function.  To avoid the loop, use the `Like`  operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx.  Instead of `If InStr(1, lineString, searchTerm, vbTextCompare) Then`, try `If .Cells(1,1) Like "*" & searchTerm & "*" Then`

Comment: @bp_ `Like` can do anything that `Instr` does, and more.  I would be very surprised if switching to a more versatile function made this run quicker.

Comment: @Degustaf have you tested this?  I'm curious to see which one is best if you can provide some feedback.  Also, @metronomadic, using `vbBinaryCompare` will be much faster than `vbTextCompare` if you can avoid it.

Comment: Thank you! @Degustaf - I used the code you provided below and it worked well. @bp_ - the `vbBinaryCompare` is much faster than the `vbTextCompare` and it also made the search case sensitive, which helps in my case. With the new code and `vbBinaryCompare` the search took just over 5 minutes. (Using `vbTextCompare` it took just under 28 minutes.) I didn't figure out the changes necessary to test out the `Workbooks.Open` or `Like` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Makah pointed out, you're opening a lot of files, which is slow.  To fix this, change the order of the loops (see the code below).  This will switch from 407,003 file opens to 367.  Along the same lines, lets create the FileSystemObject once, instead of once per file open.

Also, VBA is surprisingly slow at reading/writing data from/to Excel.  We can deal with this by loading largw blocks of data into VBA all at once with code like

```
dim data as Variant
data = Range("A1:Z16000").value
```

And then writing it back to Excel in a large block like

```
Range("A1:Z16000").value = data
```

I have also added in code to dynamically check the dimension of your data.  We assume that the data starts in cell `A2`, and if `A3` is empty, we use the single cell `A2`.  Otherwise, we use `.End(xlDown)` to move down to just above the first empty cell in column `A`.  This is the equivalent of pressing `ctrl+shift+down`.

Note:  the following code has not been tested.  Also, it requires a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" for the FileSystemObjects.

```
Sub findStringMacro()
    Dim fn As String
    Dim lineString As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim searchTerm As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim txtStr As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim file_rng As Range, file_cell As Range

    Dim output As Variant
    Dim output_index() As Integer

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    Set file_rng = Range("A2")
    If IsEmpty(file_rng) Then Exit Sub
    If Not IsEmpty(file_rng.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        Set file_rng = Range(file_rng, file_rng.End(xlDown))
    End If

    If IsEmpty(Range("C2")) Then Exit Sub
    If IsEmpty(Range("C3")) Then
        output = Range("C2")
    Else
        output = Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown))
    End If

    ReDim Preserve output(1 To UBound(output, 1), 1 To file_rng.Rows.Count + 1)
    ReDim output_index(1 To UBound(output, 1))
    For i = 1 To UBound(output, 1)
        output_index(i) = 2
    Next i

    For Each file_cell In file_rng
        fn = file_cell.Value    'Range("A" & j)
        fileName = file_cell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'Range("B" & j)
        Set txtStr = FSO.OpenTextFile(fn)
        Do While Not txtStr.AtEndOfStream
            lineString = txtStr.ReadLine
            For i = 1 To UBound(output, 1)
                searchTerm = output(i, 1)   'Range("C" & i)
                If InStr(1, lineString, searchTerm, vbTextCompare) Then
                    If output(i, output_index(i)) <> fileName Then
                        output_index(i) = output_index(i) + 1
                        output(i, output_index(i)) = fileName
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        Loop
        txtStr.Close
    Next file_cell

    Range("C2").Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output

    Set txtStr = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
    Set file_cell = Nothing
    Set file_rng = Nothing
End Sub
```